# Find an explicit solution of the following system

Tags: fourier-transform, heat-equation

I need to find an explicit solution $u(x,t)$ of the system

$$\begin{cases}
\partial_x^2 u = \frac{1}{k} \partial_t u \\
u(x,0) = f(x)
\end{cases}$$

where $f(x) = x^2e^{-x^2}$, $\,x \in \mathbb{R}, \,t>0$ and $k>0$ is fixed.

I know this should be done using Fourier transform but I'm not very sure how to proceed. Also, as for the "heat problem" I know that there is a general way to approach this kind of exercises, so I'm more interested at the general approach than at the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

We use variable separation methods to solve heat equations. Assume the solution has the following form

$$u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$$

Now, we plug this into the heat equation

$$\partial_x^2u = \frac{1}{k}\partial_tu$$

$$T(t)X''(x) = \frac{1}{k}X(x)T'(t)$$

Dividing by $X(x)T(t)$ on both sides

$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = \frac{1}{k}\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} = \lambda$$

Here lambda is some constant as a function of x and t can only be equal for all x,t if they are both identically constant

Now, we solve the two linear DEs

$$X''(x) = \lambda X(x)$$

$$T'(t) = \lambda kT(t)$$

Now, the time equation gives us

$$T(t) = Ae^{(\lambda k)t}$$

Now, we need more information about the system to deduce more info, but generally natural systems decay with space and time, hence $\lambda <0$. We rewrite it as $\lambda = -\mu^2$ with $\mu > 0$

Now, we can write the general solution of $X(x)$ as

$$X(x) = B\sin(\mu x) +C\cos(\mu x)$$

Now, our general solution looks like

$$u(x,t) = e^{-\mu^2 kt}(B'\sin(\mu x) +C'\cos(\mu x))$$

$$\implies u(x,0) = B'\sin(\mu x) +C'\cos(\mu x) = x^2e^{-x^2}$$

Now we need further conditions (I think there is a spatial constrain missing, from my experience there is usually some end point boundary condition at $x=L$ which gives the harmonic modes (some insight into $\mu$).

Now, express the LHS as a fourier sum and then compare coefficients of orthogonal sin and cos functions

Comment: Wow, this is super cool. I don't have more informations than the ones I've written in the question. At the bottom, do you mean RHS? And about this, isn't painful to find a Fourier series of $x^2 e^{-x^2}$ ?

Comment: With the data I don't think you can solve the ODE uniquely

Comment: You need 3 boundary conditions (2 space and 1 time condition) corresponding to the orders of their respective linear DE